# parse.com - Possible to 'and' multiple ACLs?

Tags: parse-platform

Using parse.com.

I have the following format set up:

- `City` roles
- `Department` roles
- `Users` that belong to a specific `Department` and `City` combination (i.e. user has relation to `Department` and `City` role)

I have a `Register` class. I want to restrict access to an object in that class to a user that belongs to BOTH `Department` AND `City`. Is that possible?

I know I could have a new role for each `City`+`Department` combination but I could end up with hundreds of roles. That seems incorrect/inefficient.

Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: From the names, it sounds like Department role ought to inherit from the City role.  Does it?  (Recall that the `Role` object has a relationship column called `roles`, which is a list of roles it inherits from).

Comment: @danh I'm not sure how that helps. It would mean all departments would have access to all City data. But I want to avoid this...I do not want departments to have access each others' data.